# How does one write a script to delete all Orders in the database without Orderline Items?

Tags: sql, sql-server

How does one write a script to delete all Orders in the database without Orderline Items?

Normally, you would delete all Orders like this:

```
delete from dbo_Orders
```

or

```
delete from dbo_Orders (where Id = 'orderid')
```

I also have a table dbo_OrderLines, which are linked in a One-to-Many relationship. I wish to delete all the orders which have no orderlines. How do I write the query?

```
delete from dbo_Orders (where this order's dbo_OrderLines count is 0)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
delete t
from dbo.Orders as t
where not exists 
(
    select 1 from dbo.OrderLines as x where x.order_id = t.order_id
)
```

I guess. you can try something like this